# How to put a value and an image of a card on an array of cards for my java project

Tags: java

For my assignment I have to put make a card memory game that allows you to click on a button to reveal a card, and then click on another button to reveal a card. If the cards match then the you get a score of three points, if they dont they are both turned upside down again and you lose a point.

The main problem that I am having is that I dont know how to assign a value and an image to each card for the score.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How far have you gotten? To get help with homework you need to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Don't expect anyone to do the homework for you.

Comment: You can easily display an ImageIcon in a JLabel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class `Card` which has properties - `image` and some identifier. When two cards are revealed compare the identifiers and add `+3` points if they match, otherwisde add`-1` points.

Answer (score 0):

As Petar said you should crate a new class Card and then you could store objects of that class on array or array list. 
You can store in the Card objects all the info you want including image and value.
Also, read about enums, could be useful here...